# OpenCV C++ Mat array to Python

Tags: python, c++, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I'm creating a fingerprint recognition system in python using opencv.

For feature extraction I am trying to follow this tutorial using Harris Corner detection.

```
Mat rescaled;
convertScaleAbs(harris_normalised, rescaled);
Mat harris_c(rescaled.rows, rescaled.cols, CV_8UC3);
Mat in[] = { rescaled, rescaled, rescaled };
int from_to[] = { 0,0, 1,1, 2,2 };
mixChannels( in, 3, &harris_c, 1, from_to, 3 );
for(int x=0; x<harris_normalised.cols; x++){
   for(int y=0; y<harris_normalised.rows; y++){
      if ( (int)harris_normalised.at<float>(y, x) > threshold_harris ){
         // Draw or store the keypoint location here, just like you decide. In our case we will store the location of the keypoint
         circle(harris_c, Point(x, y), 5, Scalar(0,255,0), 1);
         circle(harris_c, Point(x, y), 1, Scalar(0,0,255), 1);
         keypoints.push_back( KeyPoint (x, y, 1) );
      }
   }
```

}

However I am having trouble converting this line of code from C++ to Python.

```
Mat in[] = { rescaled, rescaled, rescaled };
```

No matter what I do with this line, whether its creating a Python list or Numpy.array, I just get this error:

```
Assertion failed (A.size == arrays[i0]->size) in cv::NAryMatIterator::init
```

For reference here is what I have right now:

```
harrisC = np.zeros(rescaled.shape, dtype=np.uint8)
imageArr = [rescaled, rescaled, rescaled]
harrisIn = np.array(imageArr, dtype=np.uint8)
fromTo = [0,0, 1,1, 2,2]

cv.mixChannels(harrisIn, harrisC, fromTo)
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: `cv2.mixChannels` is an overkill here, use the simpler [`cv2.merge`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga61f2f2bde4a0a0154b2333ea504fab1d) or even [`numpy.stack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html). e.g. `harrisC = cv2.merge([rescaled]*3)` instead of those 5 lines you had.

Comment: That worked perfectly, thanks.